# What is the difference between self::$bar and static::$bar in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3

What is the difference between using `self` and `static` in the example below?

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $bar = 1234;

    public static function instance()
    {
        echo self::$bar;
        echo "\n";
        echo static::$bar;
    }

}

Foo::instance();
```

#### produces

```
1234
1234
```

Comment: @deceze: That's a similar question, but it isn't a duplicate. This one asks about using the keywords with properties, while that asks about using them with constructors.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

When you use `self` to refer to a class member, you're referring to the class within which you use the keyword. In this case, your `Foo` class defines a protected static property called `$bar`. When you use `self` in the `Foo` class to refer to the property, you're referencing the same class.

Therefore if you tried to use `self::$bar` elsewhere in your `Foo` class but you had a `Bar` class with a different value for the property, it would use `Foo::$bar` instead of `Bar::$bar`, which may not be what you intend:

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $bar = 1234;
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    protected static $bar = 4321;
}
```

When you **call** a method via `static`, you're invoking a feature called [late static bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) (introduced in PHP 5.3).

In the above scenario, using `self` will result in `Foo::$bar`(1234).
And using `static` will result in `Bar::$bar` (4321) because with `static`, the interpreter takes into account the redeclaration within the `Bar` class during runtime.

```
// self
var_dump(Foo::$bar);
// (int) 1234

// static
var_dump(Bar::$bar);
// (int) 4321
```

You typically use late static bindings for methods or even the class itself, rather than properties, as you don't often redeclare properties in subclasses; an example of using the `static` keyword for invoking a late-bound constructor can be found in this related question: [New self vs. new static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197300/new-self-vs-new-static)

However, that doesn't preclude using `static` with properties as well.

Comment: You might very easily redeclare in the child class, the parent class might be a default value that the child class uses unless they re-declare. If you are in the parent class, I guess it is safe to use self::, and if in a child class, you could come up with an argument to use either one, but self:: will also work if you dont expect to re-declare ever.

Comment: go to [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/) and run this `<?php

class Foo
{
    public static $bar = 1234;
    
    public static function a(    )
    {
    echo 'static'.static::$bar;
    echo 'self'.self::$bar;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public static $bar = 4321;
    
    
}

(new Bar())->a();

?>`

Comment: The first two paragraph wording is confusing, has an ambiguous pronoun, "it", and is also redunant, as a later paragraphs explains the same information more clearly. I suggest replacing the first two paragraphs with the later paragraph that starts with "In the above scenario" to the top. That way the bottom line, cut-to-the-chase answer is at the top. It's clear and easy to follow.

Comment: Another way to think about this: `self::$abc`, when used inside `class Foo` is the same as saying `Foo::$abc`. It won't be affected by any re-declaration of `$abc` in a subclass. AFAIK, the only reason to use `self` is as a shorthand, to avoid using the class name `Foo`, which may be longer. [It also means you can change the classname without changing all those places - but that isn't much of a reason IMHO.] (PHP's choice of names is unfortunate, and seems backwards; "static" is the one that can change - which is opposite to the colloquial meaning of the natural-language word "static".)

Answer (score 62):

I have small example showing difference between `self` and `static`. Using `static::` performs Late Static Binding and thus it binds the variable value from child class.

```
class A { // Base Class
    protected static $name = 'ClassA';
    public static function getSelfName() {
        return self::$name;
    }
    public static function getStaticName() {
        return static::$name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected static $name = 'ClassB';
}

echo A::getSelfName(); // ClassA
echo A::getStaticName(); // ClassA

echo B::getSelfName(); // ClassA
echo B::getStaticName(); // ClassB
```

Answer (score 35):

**With `self` call:**

```php
class Phone
{
    protected static $number = 123;
    
    public function getNumber()
    {
        return self::$number;
    }
}
```

```php
class Fax extends Phone
{
    protected static $number = 234;
}

// Displays: "123"
echo (new Fax)->getNumber();
```

You can see above, even though we have overridden the `$number` with our `Fax` class, `getNumber()` still returns `123`.

This because we have asked PHP to give us the variable where it was defined in -- which will return `Phone`s variable instead.

If we swap the `self` call with `static`, we will get `Fax`s overridden value instead:

**With `static` call:**

```php
class Phone
{
    protected static $number = 123;
    
    public function getNumber()
    {
        // return self::$number;

        return static::$number;
    }
}
```

```php
class Fax extends Phone
{
    protected static $number = 234;
}

// Displays: "234"
echo (new Fax)->getNumber();
```

Comment: Very straight forward and not confusing example.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned one of the main differences is that `static` allows for late static bindings. One of the most useful scenarios that I found was for creating Base classes for Singleton Classes:

```php
class A { // Base Class
    protected static $name = '';
    protected static function getName() {
        return static::$name;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    protected static $name = 'MyCustomNameB';
}
class C extends A {
    protected static $name = 'MyCustomNameC';
}

echo B::getName(); // MyCustomNameB
echo C::getName(); // MyCustomNameC
```

Using `return static::$name` in the Base class will return what was statically attached when it was extended. If you were to use `return self::$name` then `B::getName()` would return an empty string as that is what is declared in the Base class.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe this self-explained code helps you:

```
class Foo 
{
    protected static $bar = 'parent value';
     
    public static function test() 
    {
         var_dump('I am your father');
         var_dump('self:: here means '.self::$bar);
         var_dump('static:: here means '.static::$bar);
    }
}
     
class Bar extends Foo 
{
     protected static $bar = 'child value';
     
     public static function test() 
     {
         parent::Test();
     
         var_dump('I am the child');
         var_dump('self:: here means '.self::$bar);
         var_dump('static:: here means '.static::$bar);
     }
}

Bar::test();
Foo::test();
```

This produces the following output (I have added Line Breaks for clarity):

```
'I am your father' (length=16)
'self:: here means parent value' (length=30)
'static:: here means child value' (length=31)

'I am the child' (length=14)
'self:: here means child value' (length=29)
'static:: here means child value' (length=31)

'I am your father' (length=16)
'self:: here means parent value' (length=30)
'static:: here means parent value' (length=32)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short version

Both `self::` and `static::` refer to static properties/functions in a parent class.  But where `self::` gets something from the class that *defines* the function, `static::` gets something from the class that *executes* the function.

#### Example

```
class Parent
{
    static $best_afternoon = ' take a nap.';
    static $opinion_of_plan = ' enjoy';

    $name;

    function __construct($name){$this->name = $name;}

    function plan()
    {
        echo $this->name . ' will' .  self::$best_afternoon;
    }
    function nap()
    {
        echo $this->name . ' will' . static::$opinion_of_plan . ' it.';
    }
}
```

```
class Child extends Parent
{
    static $best_afternoon = ' run around.';
    static $opinion_of_plan = ' dislike';
}
```

```
$mother = new Parent('Alice');
$son = new Child('Ben');
```

The Child class has its own best-afternoon and opinion values, but every `Child` inherits both the plan and nap functions from the Parent class. But while the nap function gets the overridden (late-bound) values using `static::`, the plan function **references its original context** because it uses `self::` instead.

```
$mother->plan(); //> "Alice will take a nap."
$son->plan(); //> "Ben will take a nap."

$mother->nap(); //> "Alice will enjoy it."
$son->nap(); //> "Ben will dislike it."
```

Of course if children had their own plan function, calling `$son->plan()` might return something completely different. And of course asking Ben directly what was the best afternoon would still return the overridden value from the Child class.

```
echo $mother::$best_afternoon; //> " take a nap."
echo $son::$best_afternoon; //> " run around."
```