# Laravel late static binding as static::whereIn

Tags: php, laravel, late-static-binding

Ok, I read and feel I have some understandings about PHP late static binding for methods and variables. But from line 28 in [this code on Laravel 5](https://github.com/ChuckHeintzelman/l5beauty/blob/master/app/Tag.php), it uses with `whereIn` which is a Laravel Collection method. I don't understand what's going on here, `static::whereIn()`. Where is the collection so that you can use `whereIn()`.

```
/**
 * Add any tags needed from the list
 *
 * @param array $tags List of tags to check/add
 */
public static function addNeededTags(array $tags)
{
    if (count($tags) === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $found = static::whereIn('tag', $tags)->lists('tag')->all();

    foreach (array_diff($tags, $found) as $tag) {
        static::create([
            'tag' => $tag,
            'title' => $tag,
            'subtitle' => 'Subtitle for '.$tag,
            'page_image' => '',
            'meta_description' => '',
            'reverse_direction' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is using **wherIn()** from the model, not the collection, the Tag class in extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#104823):

```
class a
{
    static protected $test = "class a";

    public function static_test()
    {
        echo static::$test; // Results class b
        echo self::$test; // Results class a
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    static protected $test = "class b";
}

$obj = new b();
$obj->static_test();
```

So `static::whereIn()` refers to `Tag::whereIn()`. Same goes for `static::create()`

Comment: Another useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php).

Comment: Thanks. But your example is about variables. But Tag is a model. So how is it related?

Comment: In the scope of laravel `Tag` is a model. In the scope of OOP `Tag` is an object. In the scope of programming `Tag` is a dedicated space within the language, representing some concept or containing a value. So are variables.