# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\kotekli-clup\oop\class\DB.php on line 32

Tags: php, function, class, fatal-error

I've got a big problem:

I'm writing a new WebApp without a Framework.
I'm using xampp and sublime text.
I dont know how can i solve this problem.

An example how my DB.php written

```
class DB{

    private static  $_baglan = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $hatalar = false,
            $sonuc,
            $_sayac = 0;

            public function __construct(){
                try{

                    $this -> _pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::getir('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::getir('mysql/db'), Config::getir('mysql/kullanici_adi'), Config::getir('mysql/sifre') );
                    // echo 'baglandi';
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }

            public static function baglan(){
                if (!isset(self::$_baglan)) {
                    self::$_baglan = new DB();
                    // echo 'baglandi';
                }
                return self::$_baglan;
            }

            public static function query($sql, $parametre=array()){

                $this->_hatalar = false;  // line 32
                if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                    $x = 1;
                    if (count($parametre)) {
                        foreach ($parametre as $param) {
                            $this->_query->bindValue($x, $parametre);
                            $x++;
                        } 
                    }
                    if ($this->_query->execute()) {
                        $this->sonuc=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        $this->_sayac=$this->_query->rowCount();
                    }else{
                        $this->_hatalar=true;
                    }
                }
                return $this;
            }

            public function eylem($eylem, $tablo, $where=array()){

                if (count($where)===3) {

                    $operatorler = array('=', '<', '>', '>=', '<=');
                    $alan = $where[0];
                    $operator = $where[1];
                    $deger = $where[2];
                    if (in_array($operator, $operatorler)) {
                        $sql = "{$eylem} FROM {$tablo} WHERE {$alan} {$operator} ?";
                        if (!$this->query($sql, array($deger))->hatalar()) {
                            return $this;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            public function getir($tablo, $where){
                return $this->eylem('SELECT *', $tablo, $where);
            }
            public function sil($tablo, $where){
                return $this->eylem('DELETE', $tablo, $where);
            }

            public function hatalar(){
                return $this->hatalar();
            }

}
```

In my index.php I'm loading maybe

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

// echo Config::getir('mysql/host');
// calismadi $kullanici = DB::baglan() -> query("SELECT kullanici_adi FROM uye WHERE kullanici_adi = ?", array('oguzhan'));
$kullanici = DB::baglan()->getir('uye', array('kullanici_adi', '=', 'oguzhan'));

if ($kullanici->hatalar()) {
    echo 'Kullanıcı yok';
}else{
    echo 'Var';
}
```

Why is the error coming?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by removing the `static` keyword from the `query` method.

You can only use `$this` on instantiated objects. `self` or `static` references the class itself, not any instantiated objects of the class.

```
class Person{

    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function greet(){
        echo 'Hello my name is ' . $this->name;
    }
}

$person = new Person('Thomas');
$person->greet(); // prints 'Hello my name is Thomas'
```

`$this` works in this example because we first instantiated the object using the `new` keyword. We are also not using the `static` keyword on the of the `methods` and `variables`.

`self` and `static` act only on the `class` itself and not on the instantiated  `object`. The difference between `self` and `static` [is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php).

Here is an example of `self` usage, notice the use of the `static` keyword on the `methods` and `variables` of the `class`:

```
class StaticClass{
    private static $variable = '';
    public static function change(string $variable){
        self::$variable = $variable;
    }
    public static function print(){
        echo self::$variable;
    }
}

StaticClass::change('Hello');
StaticClass::print(); // print 'Hello'
```