# oop - using parent parameters in child/inherited function

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have the following script:

```
<?php
class A {
    protected static $aliases = [];

    public static function doSomething()
    {
        foreach (self::$aliases as $column => $alias) {
           // do something
           echo "$column: $alias" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
class B extends A {
    protected static $aliases = [
        'id' => 'real_id',
        'name' => 'real_name',
    ];
}

$obj = B::doSomething(); // does nothing
```

How could I make B inherit the function but use it's own parameters? I have attempted to create a `getInstance` type function, however I don't think I understood the concept correctly and didn't work. I have since moved this function into a trait -- it still seems to give the same result.

Any and all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Does this question answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `self::$aliases` to `static::$aliases` to refer to `B`'s aliases within `A`.

See here: https://3v4l.org/h3dP4

```
<?php

class A {
    protected static $aliases = [];

    public static function doSomething()
    {
        foreach (static::$aliases as $column => $alias) {
           // do something
           echo "$column: $alias" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
class B extends A {
    protected static $aliases = [
        'id' => 'real_id',
        'name' => 'real_name',
    ];
}

$obj = B::doSomething();
```

This answer does a better job explaining *why* this works: [What is the difference between self::$bar and static::$bar in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using static to access the child property like this

```
public static function doSomething()
{
    foreach (static::$aliases as $column => $alias) {
       // do something
       echo "$column: $alias" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Take a look http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php for better reference