# PHP static properties and const overriding

Tags: php, static

I'm wanting to create an class inheriting (extending) another PHP class with a protected const that I want to override in my extending class.

I created a parent class (A for the example) and an inheriting class (B for the example). `class A` has a `protected const` (named CST) defined. `class B` overrides this const as well.

When calling a method class B inherited from A that displays `self::CST`, the printed value is the CST value from A, not the const CST overrided in B.

I observe the same behavior with a static property named `$var`.

It seems that `self` used in methods is always refering to the defining class (A in my example) and not the class used for calling the static method.

```
class A
{
        protected static $var = 1;
        protected const CST = 1;

        public static function printVar()
        {
                print self::$var . "\n";
        }

        public static function printCST()
        {
                print self::CST . "\n";
        }

}

class B extends A
{
        protected static $var = 2;
        protected const CST =2;
}

A::printVar();
A::printCST();
B::printVar();
B::printCST();
```

Is there a way to permit my static method `printCST()` to display 2 when called with `B::printCST()` without rewriting the method in `class B` and to benefit code reusability of OOP?

Comment: Have you tried using `static::CST` instead of `self::CST`?

Comment: No. I was not aware of this way to refer to a static constant or property...

I just successfully tested it.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Dharman suggested to use `static::CST` instead of `self::CST`.

This was the solution to my problem.

Comment: Now that I know the existence of "static::" form, I found very interesting information about the difference between "self::" and "static::": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php