# Reference to function in parent class fails

Tags: php

buildTableName() should convert the class name from "FooRepository" to "foo" but it returns an empty string although the class name is correct when printed in function query(). What's wrong in here?

```
abstract class Repository
{

    protected function buildTableName(): string
    {
        $shortName = (new \ReflectionClass(self::class))->getShortName();
        $tableName = str_replace('Repository', '', $shortName);
        return strtolower($tableName);
    }

}

class FooRepository extends Repository
{
    public function query()
    {   
        echo "my class is ".self::class;
        echo $this->buildTableName();
    }
}


(new FooRepository())->query();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710099/what-is-the-difference-between-selfbar-and-staticbar-in-php

Comment: Because self::class in buildTableName always refers to Repository class. Change self to static keyword