# How to access a constant from an object instead of its class?

Tags: php, constants

I need to access a constant that belongs to a class, but instead of writing the class' name explicitly, I want to retrieve it from the object directly. The object is a property of another object.

```
$this->fetcher::BASE_URL
```

This statement produces the error `syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing PHP Class Constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447541/accessing-php-class-constants)

Comment: Just a thought: `($this->fetcher)::BASE_URL`

Comment: @Dencker Already tried that, gives error unfortunately...

Comment: I think I recall that your initial syntax is actually possible in 5.6, although I'm not sure. If it's an option and you think it's worth it, you could try upgrading.

Comment: Make it mandatory that $this->fetcher is an object that gives its own base url. IMO better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly work-around....

```
<?php
class simpleClass {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->fetcher = new simpleClass2();
    }

    public function printBaseURL() {
        $fetcher = $this->fetcher;
        print 'Base URL: ' . $fetcher::BaseUrl;
    }
}

class simpleClass2 {
    const BaseUrl = 'one';
}


$simpleClass = new simpleClass();

$simpleClass->printBaseURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to return the constant

```
class MyClass
{
   function getConstant() {
       return  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
   }
}
```

Then call that function

```
$class = new MyClass();
$class->getConstant();
```

Or simply call the constant

`MyClass::CONSTANT;`

You can find more information about accessing constants within classes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). Look at the "user contributed notes", very good examples with explanation there.

Comment: I'd rather not use extra functions for something that should be achievable with basic language constructs. Is there some cleaner way?