# Composer Project accessing different classes

Tags: php

trying to understand something.  I have a Config class where I define a load of constants.  In one of my other classes, I need to use one of the constants from Config.  So I start off by using the class

```
use \CONFIG\Config;
```

In my class constructor, I then assign the class to a variable

```
public function __construct() {
    $config = new Config;
}
```

In the consturctor, I can then get access to a constant by doing something like this

```
$config::BASE_PATH;
```

So I dont seem to get any complaints when doing this.  If I create a class variable though, and change my constructor to the following

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->config = new Config;
    $this->config::BASE_PATH;
}
```

It complains that it is using an incorrect access to a static class member.

Why does it seem to work as a local variable, but not as a class variable?

Thanks

Comment: Huh. `::` is not listed on the operator precedence page at php.net. My guess is that the scope resolution is happening before the `->` is applied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing PHP Class Constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447541/accessing-php-class-constants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to Composer.
Its a syntax problem of PHP, while accessing class constants.

The syntax `$this->myclass::CONSTANT` to access a class constant is not supported in PHP version below PHP 7.

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/YmaHq)

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

    function showConstant() {
        echo  self::CONSTANT . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::CONSTANT . "\n";

$classname = "MyClass";
echo $classname::CONSTANT . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

class B 
{
   function __construct()
   {
       $this->myclass = new MyClass();
       $this->myclass->showConstant();

       /**
        * #### This will not work in PHP Version below PHP 7! ####
        */
       echo $this->myclass::CONSTANT;
   }
}

$b = new B;
?>
```