# how to change non static variable to static method in php

Tags: php, variables, static, non-static

I am calling constant variable like this, but it show errors, How to solve this?
I don't calling it like these code below,

```
$b = new A()
$b::$test
```

here my code

```
class A {
   const test = 4;
}

class B {

  private $a = null;
  public function __construct(){
      $this->$a = new A();
  }

  public function show(){
     echo $this->$a::test;
  }

}

$b = new B();
$b->show();
```

How to calling static variable test in class A?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing PHP Class Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447541/accessing-php-class-constants). It's not a variable, it's a constant.

Comment: I saw that you have answered, but wanted to add some minor thing, try to use constant variables with Uppercase, for example, const TEST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing is fine except `$this->$a::test;` and `$this->$a = new A();`. You have to use property without `$` sign like below

```
class A {
   const test = 4;
}

class B {

  private $a = null;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->a = new A();
  }

  public function show()
  {
     echo $this->a::test;
  }
}

$b = new B();
$b->show();
```

Comment: Hi @Vibha Chosla

I am solve my problem with this:

$test = $this->a;
echo $test::test;